# Change context of intent android

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I have a service start with:

```
override fun onActivityResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        resultCode: Int,
        data: Intent?
    ) {
        if (requestCode == com.robertohuertas.endless.MainActivity.REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    val intentx:Intent =ScreenCaptureService.getStartIntent(this,resultCode,data)
                    startService(intentx)
```

when phone reboot i will restart serive. i saved intent in `sharedPreferences`. But when phone after reboot context is different,now i get intent as code(`intentx`):

```
class StartReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private val PREFS_KEY_intent = "myPreferncesintent"
    private val PASSWORD_KEY_intent = "myPreferncesintent"
    var intentx: Intent? =null

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
            context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY_intent, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val key= sharedPreferences.getString(PASSWORD_KEY_intent, "")
        try {
            intentx= Intent.parseUri(key, 0)
        } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

in short Example :`Intent intent = new Intent(context, com.robertohuertas.endless.ScreenCaptureService.class);` How to change context in this "intent"

Comment: So sad!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sad day!!!!!!!!

Comment: So so poring ti_m_e

Comment: road code to moon

Comment: ***"How to change context in this "intent""*** - What do you mean by that? Why do you need to change the context? And why do you saved the intent in the first place? Make it clear of what you're really trying to achieve here.

Comment: @Darkman i have a `mediaproject service` started in `Mainactivity`, in which i get `intent` with `context  X` and a binding in variable `data:intent?` as code. After reboot phone i want to start `mediaproject service` again,now the `context` has changed, how can my intent change context?. Maybe this approach is wrong, do you find it feasible?.